# Render formatted HTML string on webpage

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a bunch of HTML text that looks like this:

```
<p><strong>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique</strong> senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, 
ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
<em>Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.</em> Mauris placerat
```

This is text that a user will post forum, and this formatted string is then stored on a server. I am displaying this text on another page, but would like it to be render as the user formatted it, eg:

**Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique** senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, 
ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
*Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.* Mauris placerat

I have tried using `<pre>`, `<p>`, and other tags, but they just print out the raw HTML instead of using the formatting given. I am currently using Angular.JS for my page.

Sample text obtained from http://html-ipsum.com/, "Kitchen Sink" example

Answer (score 1):

You are likely storing the string `uuencoded`, so it displays the codes shown literally.

I'd double check your raw data store to verify this.

In any case **THIS IS NOT A RECOMMENDED WAY TO APPROACH YOUR CODE**. You are basically inviting a malicious user to potentially inject malicious code into the your other users.

When allowing users to input any html, it is best to only allow a small subset of tags (and a small subset of attributes), and even then it is very hard to get right.

See [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) Tutorial](https://www.veracode.com/security/xss) for more.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like, at some point during the process of storing your HTML, you have escaped the HTML entities (i.e. converted `<` to `&lt;`, that sort of thing).

I don't know what language you're working in, but it's possible to unescape HTML characters in pretty much any language. [Here's an answer about doing it in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912522/992504). The [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) method will do the trick in PHP. For whatever language you're working in, just do research on "unescape html entities" in that language.

Warning: since you are unescaping HTML, there's the risk that the user might have written something naughty (i.e. like a `<script>` tag with some malicious JS code). Make sure you're cleaning out any nasty HTML somewhere along the line.